# How to change some items in Series (depending if items in some list or not)

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have columns in my dataset. There I have a big numbers of different cuisine styles.

I've made a list with top 20 cuisine styles and I want to change other styles to 'other'.

I have a code:

```
for i in data.explode('Cuisine Style')['Cuisine Style']:
    if i not in top_cuisine_list:
        i = 'Other'
```

Why this code doesn't work? I don't have some errors, but after code I have no changes is `['Cuisine Style']` column...

Answer (score 0):

Using `df.apply()`:

```
df['Cuisine Style'] = df['Cuisine Style'].apply(lambda x: ['Other' if y in top_cuisine_list else y for y in x])
```